# How to calculate the Average size of the last 5 candlesticks in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

I'm new, and trying to figure this out.

I am trying to write a script to calculate the average size of the last 5 bars (High-Low) for the last five candlesticks of a stock.

I know how to write the logic, but I am still finding my way around Pine Script.

```
Calculate Last 5 Bar Sizes
Bar3Range = Bar 3 (High - Low)
Bar4Range = Bar 4 (High - Low)
Bar5Range = Bar 5 (High - Low)
Bar6Range = Bar 6 (High - Low)
Bar7Range = Bar 7 (High - Low)

//  Calculate Average Bar Size
Last5BarAverage = (Bar3Range + Bar4Range + Bar5Range + Bar6Range + Bar7Range) / 5
If Bar 2 is >= 2 * Bar1Range then True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//@version=4
study("")
plot(sma(high - low, 5))
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to the whole coding forum, so thanks for the heads up.

Comment: np.Welcome and gl with your project.

Comment: @PineCoders-LucF How can we check that at least two candles are closed within the body of the previous candle? hope you understand my question. An slightly big candle than average and after that alteast two or max 10 candles are clossed within the body of that candle. This is what I am looking for.

Comment: Hi, You need to create a new question. Comments are not useful to discuss code. You can ping me again in a new comment to that question.